# Laravel Eloquent Trouble

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

hi guys I got lot of confuse , I made it some relationship with tables but... please help me thx for any helps [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tniOM.png)

I got one product table , and realated urun_entity table, urun_entity tables related with atributes color,weight etc etc..

and my urun_entity table looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUccB.png)

```
$urun = DB::table('urun_entity')
        ->join('ucolor','urun_entity.id','=','ucolor.id')
        ->join('urun','urun_entity.urun_id','=','urun.id')->get();
```

I'd try fetch data like this, ucolor id only fetch one data how can I fetch all datas on color tables

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use "urun_entity.ucolor_id" in your "ucolor" join. The correct relationship should be like the following:

```php
$urun = DB::table('urun_entity')
    #### The mistake was in the below line.
    ->join('ucolor','urun_entity.ucolor_id','=','ucolor.id')
    ->join('urun','urun_entity.urun_id','=','urun.id')->get();
```

Comment: Oh thank you Mr Onur , I understand that my mistake